# Prime Number Rows in a Pascal's Triangle (complement)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

You have some observations that I believe complement the properties in question [Prime Number Rows in a Pascal's Triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834493/prime-number-rows-in-a-pascals-triangle).

1. Because of the way we count the rows that we are starting in Zero, and because of the resulting fraction of the binomial coefficient, then only in the rows of prime numbers, we will have only 1 and 0 as results of the application of Prime modular arithmetic.

- We will always have two results as 1, where one at the beginning and the other at the end of the rows. And there will be (Prime-1) consecutive 0's results between the two 1's.
- Rows different from Prime number will have results different from Zero between the 1's.
- For example, (elements in row 7) mod 7 is (1,7,21,35,35,21,7,1) mod 7 ≡ (1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1). We got two results as 1 and (6=7-1) consecutive Zeroes between the 1's.

2. Now, if we count the rows using the Tally counting, then only in the rows of prime numbers we will have the values 1 and (P-1) alternately as results of the application of Prime modular arithmetic.

- In the other rows will appear more than 2 different results.
- For example, (elements in row 7 using Tally counting) mod 7 is (1,6,15,20,15,6,1) mod 7 ≡ (1,6,1,6,1,6,1).
- This operation is equivalent to using row count starting at Zero, but taking rows (Prime-1) and applying Prime mod to them. That is, taking up the row 6 above and applying mod 7 we have (1,6,15,20,15,6,1) mod 7 ≡ (1,6,1,6,1,6,1).

3. The property (elements in row Prime) mod Prime ≡ (1,0,0,0,...,0,0,0,1) will be extended to all other rows that are any power of Prime. They form the bases of the Sierpinski's triangles inverted. Only these specific bases join the two Units at the edge of the Pascal triangle.

Someone would like to make a formal proof?

Comment: Your question will be closed if you don' t edit it because of the formatting.

Comment: What is your question?