# How would be a possible algorithm for the negative rows of the Pascal's triangle?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When we consider Pascal's triangle as being the one in [Prime Number Rows in a Pascal's Triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834493/prime-number-rows-in-a-pascals-triangle?noredirect=1&lq=1), one of the things that always puzzled me in mathematics was how would be the continuity of Pascal's triangle in the negative rows.

Comment: What are the negative rows of Pascal's triangle? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I am not sure now if here is the right forum to issue background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, my current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc. I submitted some backgrounds in a Journal. Please, feel free to delete this question by now. Otherwise, I would like to wait the publishing to continue here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since the $k$th entry of the $n$th row of Pascal's triangle is $\frac{n \cdot (n - 1) \cdot (n - k + 1)}{k!}$, we can extend this formula to negative $n$ by just plugging it into the same formula. So for $n, k \geq 0$, we would have
\begin{align}
\binom{-n}{k} & = \frac{(-n) \cdot (-n - 1) \cdot (-n - k + 1)}{k!} \\
& = (-1)^k \frac{(n + k - 1)(n + k - 2) \dots (n)}{k!} \\
& = (-1)^k \binom{n + k - 1}{k}.
\end{align}

It's more difficult to extend the formula to negative $k$, since $k!$ isn't defined for negative $k$ (even the real-valued extension of the factorial function, the gamma function, isn't defined on negative integers).